# How can I submit a Form with <a> that Was Created Appending Stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

This is what I currently have:

```
var popupContent = ''
    function createMessage(msg,pl) {
        return [
            "<p>" + msg + "</p>",
            "<form action='" + pl + "' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>",
                "<ul class='cd-buttons no_margin'>",
                    "<li><a class='submit'>Yes</a></li>",
                    "<li><a class='popup-close'>No</a></li>",
                "</ul>",
            "</form>",
            "<a class='cd-popup-close popup-close img-replace'>Close</a>"
        ].join('');
    }

    //Accept Employement Request
    $('.popup1').on('click', function() {
        employeeName = $(this).siblings('.js-employee-name').text();
        var message = "Are you sure you want to hire <b>" + employeeName + "</b>?"
        var postLink = "/hire-employee"

        createMessage();

        $(".cd-popup-container").append( createMessage(message, postLink) );
    });

    $('.submit').click(function(){
        $('form').submit();
    });
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

So how can I submit this the form created by the createMessage function when the  with that class submit is clicked?

Thank you very much. Let me know if I wasn;t clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `<button>` instead of anchor and use the default behavior of the button.

*Use*

```
<button class='submit'>Yes</button>
```

---

However, Solution for your immediate problem.

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating elements dynamically.**

You need to use  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(staticParentElement).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

*Example*

```
$(".cd-popup-container").on('click', '.submit', function(event){
    $('form').submit();
    event.preventDefault(); //Cancel default behaviour of anchor
});
```